# `docker-compose up` doesn't create a persistent volume for PostgreSQL container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

I am trying to create a persistent volume storage for a postgres docker container. Because I will have some other services within this docker environment, I am using `docker-compose` to start the container.

The contents of my `docker-compose.yml` file are:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.3
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/posgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

I run the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

Now, based on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/), and [this example](https://medium.com/shot-code/running-django-postgresql-containers-and-persisting-data-with-docker-4dd8e4dd5361), I expect to have one persistent volume created, with its name including `postgres-data` (e.g., `postgres-volume_postgres-data`).

Instead, two volumes are created:

```
docker volume ls
```

Output:

```
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     a53a5b161f0fefca840e2f0cd2a97ad019864dea23c7f23f07c94e6be7ace601
local     postgres-volume_postgres-data
```

Inspecting the volumes:

```
docker volume inspect a53a5b161f0fefca840e2f0cd2a97ad019864dea23c7f23f07c94e6be7ace601
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-02-07T19:12:04Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/a53a5b161f0fefca840e2f0cd2a97ad019864dea23c7f23f07c94e6be7ace601/_data",
        "Name": "a53a5b161f0fefca840e2f0cd2a97ad019864dea23c7f23f07c94e6be7ace601",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Inspecting the second volume:

```
docker volume inspect postgres-volume_postgres-data
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-02-07T19:12:02Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "postgres-volume",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "postgres-data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres-volume_postgres-data/_data",
        "Name": "postgres-volume_postgres-data",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Of these two volumes only the `a53a5b161f0fefca840e2f0cd2a97ad019864dea23c7f23f07c94e6be7ace601` is active and all the data seem to be stored within this volume.

The effect is that when I use `docker-compose down`, all data saved to the database when the container was running are lost, i.e., the data are not persisted, and they are not available after running the `docker-compose up` again.

What I am doing wrong?

(I am using macOS Big Sur, v.11.4.)

Docker & `docker-compose` versions:

```
➜  ~ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

➜  ~ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
docker-py version: 5.0.0
CPython version: 3.9.0
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
```

Comment: The container path `/var/lib/postgresql/data` needs a `t` in it.  That could cause the anonymous volume you're seeing.

Comment: @David Maze, yes, that was exactly the issue, thanks! I even manually checked the path before, by using `docker exec -it postgres /bin/bash`, but I didn't copy-pasted the exact path -- that was my error. Then I would have spotted/solved the error. Now everything works and the data are persisted after `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is called a 'bind mount' where a directory on the host is mapped to a directory in the container.

The syntax is slightly different if you want to create a volume. Do this instead

```
- postgres-data:/var/lib/posgresql/data
```

(i.e. no path information before the volume name)

Comment: Hans Kilian, thanks for the advice. The actual issue for the double volume was a typo, noticed by @David Maze in his comment under my question. Nevertheless, I also used your suggestion, so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are mounting a host path. Its contents are lost when removing containers. What you want to have is a named volume. After the initial creation of a named volume, you can reuse it across services and it will be persisted on following invocations.

In `docker-compose`, the following would create the named volume `myapp` and use it in the service called 'frontend'. The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose) and [compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) explain this well.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  frontend:
    image: node:lts
    volumes:
      - myapp:/home/node/app
volumes:
  myapp:
```

Actually, you also can create volumes externally with `docker volume create myapp` and then reference them inside `docker-compose` setups adding `external: true`.

```yaml
volumes:
  myapp:
    external: true
```

Comment: alexanderdavide, thank you for the clear example and additional link to the documentation. I wanted to have everything managed by a single `docker-compose` file, so the tip about creating external volumes is useful, but not for me, in this case. The actual reason for two volumes being created was found by @David Maze (see his comment under my question). I am going to mark @Hans Kilman 's answer as "the solution", because he was first, and he provided the exact line I needed (although also with the aforementioned typo). I would have upvoted you answer as well, but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @MikolajBuchwald
No problem! I hope my answer still added to your understanding.

Comment: Yes, it did, thank you!